# Failed to declare and display UTF-8 character properly in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, utf-8

I have a JSON object where one attribute contains a static special character - https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F514

I have tried to store the string both as encoded UTF-8 `"\xF0\x9F\x94\x94"` 
or tried to print it using its HEX value - `String.fromCharCode(0x1F514)` or decimal value `String.fromCharCode(128276)`
But it all results in an empty charater/empty square character in Google Chrome.

How can I please store this character properly, statically in a simple JSON `{header1:"____"}` and then echo it?

Also not able to display it in IntelliJ - so if you have a comment regarding this side issue would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the font doesn't have support for such symbol, hence the square character being drawn. If there is not an specific reason as why you are using this character, you could draw it with an icon, or using a character in an icon font.

Comment: Did not cross my mind for some reason... need to refer to a font which supports this kind of character.

Answer (score 2):

For historial reasons, JavaScript doesn't have full Unicode support because language creators assumed that UTF-16 would never need more than 2-bytes to encode a single character. JSON inherits that and `\u` entities only accept 4 hexadecimal characters.

You need to use a workaround that basically consists on splitting the actual 4-byte UTF-16 character in two 2-byte characters, as in:

```js
var raw = "";
var doesNotWork = "\u1F514";
var works = "\uD83D\uDD14";
console.log(raw, doesNotWork, works);
```

... or get rid of entities and just dump the actual binary character:

```js
var data = [""];
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(json, JSON.parse(json));
```